# model item passed into the dictionary is of type PagedList.PagedList[] but this dictionary requires a model item of type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to use view models in my project but I have this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'PagedList.PagedList`1[ContosoUniversity.Models.Course]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.CourseViewModel]'.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

        var courses = courseService.GetAll();

        var coursesViewList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Course>, IEnumerable<CourseViewModel>>(courses);

        var model = coursesViewList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, PageSize);

        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.CourseViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Credits)
        </th>
        <th>
            Students
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Credits)
        </td>
        <td>
            @string.Join(",", item.Enrollments.Select(e => e.Student.FullName))
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CourseID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CourseID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>


@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

Could somebody help me to resolve a problem please?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, please try to understand it. Put breakpoints in your controller and check the contents of the various variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing Model of type `PagedList.PagedList1<ContosoUniversity.Models.Course>` while your View is strongly typed with `IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.CourseViewModel>`.

You need to pass `IEnumerable<T>` from action or set Model of View to `PagedList<T>` or you can  overcome this issue by  wrapping it inside a ViewModel in following way:

```
public class CoursesVM
{
    public PagedList.IPagedList<CourseViewModel> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

In action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

    var courses = courseService.GetAll();

    var coursesViewList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Course>, IEnumerable<CourseViewModel>>(courses);

    var model = new CoursesVM();
    model.Courses = coursesViewList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, PageSize);

    return View(model);
}
```

and in View:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.CoursesVM
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Credits)
        </th>
        <th>
            Students
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Courses) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Credits)
        </td>
        <td>
            @string.Join(",", item.Enrollments.Select(e => e.Student.FullName))
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CourseID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CourseID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: thank you but now different error :  CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.CourseViewModel' because 'ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.CourseViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'getEnumerator'

Comment: you are iterating wrong iterate on its property List not on single object